# Firebase Auth get current user password

Tags: firebase

I want to get the password of the current user that is login so i can rewrite his password written in firestore, my app is about dementia patient so i need to store password in firestore so the one managing the patient can see the password

hope any one has a method to get password from FirebaseAuth

Comment: Store two separate passwords, one for the patient and on for the manager. Having it in clear text is basically never a good idea. That also gives you info on who is logged in, the patient or the manager if you need to figure out who did what.

Comment: yea i know thats not a good idea but the main purpose of this app is to monitor a patient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to my question, thanks for those who suggested answer ^^
This is the answer to my solution hope can help

Just get the password every sucessful login and save it to firestore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the password from Firebase Authentication, as it doesn't store the password in cleartext. It only stores the hash and salt, both of which you can get from the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) or by [exporting the list of users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) through the CLI.

If you must capture the password, you'll have to do so at the source: in the application where the user enters it.